# Secondary DNS Server \ Domain controller

Tags: windows

I recently installed a secondary domain controller within my organization which also holds the DNS Role.
If one DC goes down I would like all client machines to look for the secondary Domain controller. How can I remotely add the secondary DNS to all client machines without having to physically go to each client machine?

Comment: Do you use DHCP to assign ip addressing configuration to your clients?

Comment: Yes I use dhcp from a router , not windows server

Comment: OK, so in your DHCP scope configuration make sure you're assigning both DNS servers to your DHCP clients.